# C++ the this pointer is always const

Tags: c++, constants

For a non const member function of class X, this pointer is of type X* const.

Then, this pointer for a member function is always const.

Then, do we always need to const cast as in:

```
void foo::p() {                        
      const_cast <int&> (member) = 1;    
}
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: you declared `p()` as const so you cant modify the members of the class.

Comment: @Koushik, you can, but you need to mark these members as `mutable`.

Comment: @izogfif yes but has he? its this context i'm refering to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> For a non const member function of class X, this pointer is of type X* const.

No, the type of the `this` pointer inside a non-const member function is just `X*` (and it is an rvalue). But even if `this` were `X* const`, that would still not prevent you from changing data members.

Your code example doesn't match your question. It shows a const member function. Inside a const member function, the type of `this` is `const X*`. You cannot change any data members inside a const member function (with the exception of data members declared as `mutable`). It is a contradiction to declare a member function as `const` if your goal is to change data members. Make up your mind.

Comment: `this pointer is of type X* const`, then this is a const pointer to pointee of type X, right ? it is a const pointer then ?

Comment: `this` is not a const pointer, but it is an rvalue, so it does not harm to think of `this` as a const pointer; you cannot reassign `this` either way.

Comment: @FredOverflow if its an rvalue how can we access members through it?am confused so.

Comment: You are probably being confused about the meaning of the term rvalue. `this` being an rvalue simply means that you cannot take the address of `this`. That is, you cannot write `&this`. Being an rvalue has nothing to do with the right-hand side of an assignment (that's what you're probably thinking; 99% of C++ texts get this completely wrong).

Comment: No. There are literal lvalues.

Comment: @Koushik Unfortunately, not quite. Almost all literals are indeed rvalues, but string literals are lvalues. If you're uncertain whether some expression `x` is an rvalue, just write `&x` and see if the compiler rejects it. (Note: this won't work if `x` is of class type and the class author has overloaded `operator&`. In that (hopefully rare) case, `&x` will work on both lvalues and rvalues.)

Comment: but if member function is not const, i can modify value of class data members no prob. i cannot alter it if member function is const, cause then this is const pointer to const X, and object of type X cannot be altered, right ?

Comment: lvalue can be accessed and modified, rvalue can be accessed only (accessor mutator), is definition enough ?

Comment: @macscholes You got it almost right except for the fact that `this` itself is never `const`, but that doesn't really make that much difference. I would stop worrying about it :)

Comment: @Koushik Just beware that most sources get this wrong. If you see something like "left/right side of an assignment", stop reading. It's wrong.

Comment: @FredOverflow yes will surely do. Bjarne's TC++PL has this topic?is there a source that you can suggest?thanks for guiding.

Comment: @Koushik I recommend watching [this video](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/move-semanticsperfect-forwarding-and-rvalue-references) first and [that video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) next. You can't understand rvalue references without understanding rvalues first, and Scott explains it well.

Answer (score 2):

> For a non const member function of class X, this pointer is of type X* const.
>
> Then, this pointer for a member function is always const.

More or less, it's an rvalue, but can seen as a const pointer, but note: The *pointer* is const, but not the pointee. That means, you cannot change which object this points to, but you can change the contents of the object.

In your example, the function is declared const:

```
void foo::p() const { 
              // ^---- here!
```

So in this case, `this` is of type `X const * const` (it's exactly an rvalue of type `X const*` but that does not matter here) - i.e. the pointer *and the pointee* are const. The latter is what really matters.

So if you want to modify members, just don't use const for the method:

```
void foo::p() {    
           //^------ no const!
      member = 1;       // perfectly legal, because *this is not const
      this->member = 1; // the same
      this = new foo;   // still illegal, this cannot be assigned to
}
```

Comment: `this` itself is never const, but I guess it does no harm to pretend it is.

Answer (score 0):

the const is after the star symbol, meaning "X* const", and not "const X* or X const*" (which are the same).
therefore it means you cannot make "this" point to different object than the one he is pointing at, but you can change the object that is being pointed, which makes sense.
"const X* or X const*" means you cannot change the object that is being pointed at the moment, but you can make the pointer point to different objects.
hope it helps(: