# Type of "this" in c++?

Tags: c++

```
struct Foo
{
 void f()
 {
 // (*)
 }
};
```

What is the type of "this" in the line marked with (*) ?

Is it **const Foo*** or **Foo*** ?

Comment: It's probably `Foo * const`

Comment: @TomKnapen no it's not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102143/c-the-this-pointer-is-always-const/

Comment: If it were `const Foo *`, that would imply you can't change the member variables in the object (imagine all the accesses having the `this->` stated explicitly). That's not the intent unless you declare the member function itself `const`.

Comment: Another voice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6067267/1715716

Answer (score 70, accepted):

n3376 9.3.2/1

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, **the keyword this is a prvalue expression** whose value
> is the address of the object for which the function is called.
>
> **The type of this in a member function of
> a class X is X***. If the member function is declared const, the type of this is const X*, if the member
> function is declared volatile, the type of this is volatile X*, and if the member function is declared
> const volatile, the type of this is const volatile X*.

Comment: That makes me wonder why they didn't make `this` a const pointer... Any particular reason?

Comment: @TomKnapen `this` is an r-value, so you can't modify it anyway. For most intents and purposes, it behaves as `X * const`. But you can't take its address, for example.

Comment: @TomKnapen: No. In hindsight, it should have been a reference, not a pointer. But `this` predates references, and the C++ tradition of not breaking existing code is really old.

Comment: @TomKnapen it makes no sense for a value to be const. What can be changed? Can a value be changed to be something else? Or can an object to be changed to contain some other value? It is the former, and the former only can be const (it has a *lifetime*, during which it gets no different value).

Comment: The type of an expression picks up the constness of the object, and will then be of a const type. See the note on 4.1p1

Answer (score 5):

Inside `f`, `this` has type `Foo *` because `f` is not a `const` member function.

You cannot call `f` on a `const Foo` object. The following is erroneous:

```
 const Foo obj;
 obj.f();
```

This is precisely because inside `Foo::f`, the `this` pointer is `Foo *` rather than `const Foo *`, and so the function call demands a pointer conversion which discards a qualifier.

The `this` pointer itself is not a variable. It is not assignable, but not because of a `const` qualifier. There is no declaration in scope such as `Foo *const this`. A `this` expression is simply not an lvalue, as a rule of the language.

The `this` pointer is not very different from `&obj`.

Answer (score 3):

The type of **this** depends on the member function.

For example for a class X, if the member functions is

1) const, Then **this** is of type const X*

2) volatile, then **this** is volatile X* etc

otherwise it is X*

Answer (score -5):

`this` refers to current object. The type of `this` in c++ is `Foo *const`.